# Why am I receiving an error when I try to sum multiple columns in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df=pd.read_excel('Canada.xlsx',sheet_name='Canada by Citizenship',skiprows=range(20),skipfooter=2)

df['Total']=df.iloc[:,'1980':'2013'].sum(axis=1)
```

### Here is the error I received:

```
TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'> with these indexers [1980] of <class 'str'>
```

I received the dataset from this [link](https://www.kaggle.com/roshansharma/immigration-to-canada-ibm-dataset/downloads/Canada.xlsx/1)

Comment: Please provide your data as code so we can execute it on our computers. Also cut it down to the columns,  rows that are necessary to reproduce your error. (Look up https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: iloc is for integer based year, but '1980' and '2013' are strings so you need to try to use .loc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The columns are integers. You can slice with:

```
df.loc[:, range(1980, 2014)].sum(1)
# or
df.iloc[:, df.columns.get_loc(1980):df.columns.get_loc(2013)+1].sum(1)

0      58639
1      15699
2      69439
3          6
4         15
       ...  
190    97146
191        2
192     2985
193     1677
194     8598
Length: 195, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

The `iloc()` function requires only positional arguments. You could use the `loc()` function to do it in on line.

Here is what it could look like :

```
df.loc[:, [1980 + i for i in range(34)] ].sum(axis=1)
```